# Can't find ItemView

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-view, android-glide

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7c9rG.png)

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsF7Z.png)

```
    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    var tvName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvName)
    var tvAge: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvAge)
    var ivProfile: ItemView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivProfile)

    fun bind(contact: Contact) {
        tvName.text = contact.name
        tvAge.text = "Age: ${contact.age}"

        Glide.with(context).load(contact.imageUrl).into (ivProfile)
    }
  }
}
```

Is there in kotlin only `MenuView.ItemView`? Because Glide expects ItemView

Error Log:

```
Type mismatch: inferred type is MenuView.ItemView but ImageView was expected.
```

And if I paste instead of `MenuView.ItemView` `ImageView` then it says:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.ImageView
                                                                                                    at com.jakob.kotlinrecyclerview.ContactAdapter$ViewHolder.<init>(ContactAdapter.kt:35)
                                                                                                    at com.jakob.kotlinrecyclerview.ContactAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(ContactAdapter.kt:17)
                                                                                                    at com.jakob.kotlinrecyclerview.ContactAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(ContactAdapter.kt:13)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `ImageView` and not `ItemView` there.

For the `ClassCastException` check that the layout has id `ivProfile` for the `ImageView` only and not e.g. in a higher-level `ConstraintLayout`.